# How to get publicKey in RSA_encrypt key-pair generation algorithm in STRING format in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, rsa

I am currently working on encryption in my flutter app wherein I am using RSA key-pair generator to get public and private key using the following code-

```
import 'package:rsa_encrypt/rsa_encrypt.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/api.dart' as crypto;

//Future to hold our KeyPair
Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair> futureKeyPair;

//to store the KeyPair once we get data from our future
crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair keyPair;

Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair<crypto.PublicKey, crypto.PrivateKey>> getKeyPair()
{
var helper = RsaKeyHelper();
return helper.computeRSAKeyPair(helper.getSecureRandom());
}
```

---

Now I want to get the keyPair.publicKey in string format but if i print keyPair.publicKey, it shows "Instance of RSA publicKey" . How can I get it in string format??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always best to use standardized formats when saving public keys. For RSA public keys you can store them in layers, much like a Matroesjka doll.

1. Encode the public key in the ASN.1 / DER format specified in the PKCS#1 RSA standard;
2. Encode that public key in a format called SubjectPublicKeyInfo which is part of the X.509 specifications - it indicates that this is indeed an RSA key;
3. Apply so called PEM "ASCII armor", which consists of a header & footer line indicating the generic SubjectPublicKeyFormat (just `PUBLIC KEY`), with a multi-line base 64 encoding of the public key from step 2 in between.

Sounds like a lot of work, but if you look [here](https://gist.github.com/proteye/982d9991922276ccfb011dfc55443d74) you'll find handy methods called `encodePublicKeyToPem` and `parsePublicKeyFromPem` that do these 3 steps for you (it actually does both 1 and 2 in the same function, which is a bit of a shame but not that important).

These keys are rather portable and are also usable by e.g. OpenSSL or PGP.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! 
I found similar implementations for "encodePrivateKeyToPemPKCS1' mentioned in the docs [https://pub.dev/packages/rsa_encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/rsa_encrypt) as the GitHub link of methods that you had sent in [https://www.programmersought.com/article/18664973041/](https://www.programmersought.com/article/18664973041/).

That GitHub link of methods can also be used for reversing the instace->string :) conversion.

Comment: everyone refers to this gist but it's broken...

Comment: @AlbertoM Thanks for notifying me, but please explain why you think it is broken so we can investigate!

Comment: RsaKeyHelper().generateKeyPair(); throws Unhandled exception:
type 'AsymmetricKeyPair<PublicKey, PrivateKey>' is not a subtype of type 'AsymmetricKeyPair<RSAPublicKey, RSAPrivateKey>'

Comment: Since the aforementioned Gist no longer works, I recommend using 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils/master/lib/src/StringUtils.dart
and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils/master/lib/src/CryptoUtils.dart @AlbertoM